# Java - Custom property for custom element

Tags: java, swing

I'm making my own element which is inherited from JButton, I want to make a custom property editor, lets say it colorTheme. I manage to assign it into netbeans property editor using getColorTheme method, which return array of string, because the colorTheme cannot be other than the values of array itself ("Type 1","Type 2","Type 3","Type 4").
So far.. I can only make the getter, not the setter, here's the pict:

(Without Setter)
[image]

(With Setter)
[image]

(What I wanted)
[image]

If possible, user cannot choose other value than those provided in the property box (including clicking the dot and assign custom value), has anyone done this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: simple question - for why reson you bothering with refused and outdated Swing GUI Framework, is there some advantage (e.g. distributed apps)

Comment: I'm not ready for javafx yet, in truth I haven't find a good javafx tuts. the reason I want to perfect this swing thing is that I want to be a Java lecturer, in which swing is a must to learn as basic java gui form. and another reason is I want to make my own swing component so that I will always use my custom swing :)

Comment: I'm not talking about Swing v.s. JavaFx (there is important to wayting for Java8 with JavaFx8), I'm talking about Mattise (Swing GUI Framework) v.s. Swing coded by hands

Comment: well I understand now :3, ummm I want to make a custom jbutton and other swing component, and add them into the pallete, so that when I want to change the color scheme I just need to choose it from property box, not re-code it..